# Ekevents gets adding multiple times in calendar?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, icalendar, ekeventstore

In my application i am adding an event to devices calendar.I am doing like this

```
if ([db.saveCalenderSettings isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]){

    NSPredicate *predicateForEventOnDate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:strtdate endDate:[strtdate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60] calendars:nil];                                     
    NSArray *eventsOnDate = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicateForEventOnDate];

    __block BOOL eventExists = NO;

    [eventsOnDate enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        EKEvent *eventToCheck = (EKEvent*)obj;

        if([note isEqualToString:eventToCheck.notes]) {
             eventExists = YES;
             *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@",eventsOnDate);
    if(! eventExists) {
        NSLog(@"Event not exists so adding");

        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = subject; //give event title you want
        event.notes = note ;
        event.startDate = strtdate;
        event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];
        event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        //   EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60*15*-1];
        //   event.alarms = [NSArray arrayWithObject:alarm];

        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

        if (!err) {

             [db setSavedtocalender:@"yes"];

        }
        else {
              //  NSLog(@" Event not created");
              [db setSavedtocalender:@"no"];

        }
    }
    else {
         NSLog(@"Event exists");
         [db setSavedtocalender:@"yes"];                             
     }
}
```

But the problem is the same event gets added multiple times in the default calendar .Can anybody tells me where i am going wrong?

Comment: @Nirav for some reason i am not able to use event identifier .so thats y i am doing like this

Comment: you by mistake tag me instead of SagarShirbhate :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi For each and every event one id is alloted.
Please Check is the event is added or not.If event added then store event id and check agin before saving event again.

For getting Event Id :

```
//save the event id if you want to access this later
NSString *eventId=event.eventIdentifier;
```

For Future Refernce :

```
// To add event in Calender App

    EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) { return; }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = @"To meet Chandu.";
        event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
        event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
        event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        event.location=@"Sandriver Technologies";
        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
        NSLog(@"%@",event.eventIdentifier);  //save the event id if you want to access this later
        eventId=event.eventIdentifier;
    }];



    //to remove event from app

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) { return; }
        EKEvent* eventToRemove = [store eventWithIdentifier:eventId];
        if (eventToRemove) {
            NSError* error = nil;
            [store removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
        }
    }];



// Note: Get all event list

  //To get Appropriate calender
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];


    if ([store respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {
        /* iOS Settings > Privacy > Calendars > MY APP > ENABLE | DISABLE */
        [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if ( granted )
             {
                 NSLog(@"User has granted permission!");
                 // Create the start date components
                 NSDateComponents *oneDayAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
                 oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1;
                 NSDate *oneDayAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents
                                                               toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                              options:0];

                 // Create the end date components
                 NSDateComponents *oneYearFromNowComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
                 oneYearFromNowComponents.year = 1;
                 NSDate *oneYearFromNow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneYearFromNowComponents
                                                                    toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                   options:0];

                 // Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
                 NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:oneDayAgo
                                                                         endDate:oneYearFromNow
                                                                       calendars:nil];

                 // Fetch all events that match the predicate
                 NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
                 NSLog(@"The content of array is%@",events);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"User has not granted permission!");
             }
         }];
    }
```

Comment: If this Answer solve your problem please make it correct.

Comment: for some reason i am not able to use event identifier .so thats i am trying to access the notes property of the event.becoz thats the only unique thing that i have

Comment: You can Check with all events comes under specific day where you are adding an event.

Comment: with which unique value if i uninstall the application